# Create an email with a trigger on mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

Im trying to auto create an email using a trigger with an employee name, example wiston churchill (Wchurchill@something.com)

as far i have this

```
    DELIMITER // 
    create TRIGGER correo
       after insert on prueba
         for each row 
         begin
           declare correo varchar(100);
           set correo = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(nombre, 1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(apellido, 2)));
           insert INTO prueba (correo) VALUES (correo2);
        end//
```

but when i try insert in the table

```
insert into prueba (nombre, apellido) values ('erik','tapia');
```

i get this error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'nombre' in 'field list'

Edit: the error says that i dont have the column, im using this table

```
create table prueba (
 nombre varchar(20),
 apellido varchar(20),
 correo varchar(100)
 );
```

Comment: There's no column `nombre` in the table `prueba`. That's what the message says, and from what you've posted here there's nothing more we can say.

Comment: the problem is that i have the column, i check the name and drop and remake the table, i should edit the post to clarify that point

Comment: If `nombre/apellido` columns cannot be edited in future then generated column is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

In the trigger you must refer to not `column` (in your case this is abstract column name from the table which is not specified in the statement) but to `NEW.column` (the reference to the value which is inserted into this column of the current row).

Also you cannot INSERT into the table which the trigger is defined on.

And you do not need in intermediate variable.

So

```
CREATE TRIGGER correo
AFTER INSERT 
ON prueba
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.correo = CONCAT( UPPER(LEFT(NEW.nombre, 1)), 
                         LOWER(SUBSTRING(NEW.apellido, 2)));
```

The trigger contains one statement - so it does not need in BEGIN-END block and DELIMITER reassign.

Answer (score 0):

To access the values of an inserted row, you have to use the `new` pseudo record, for reading and writing.

So you cannot just write `nombre`, the engine won't find that column (or variable or whatever, for some reason the error message uses "column"). You'd have to write `new.nombre`. Same goes for `apellido`.

Then, to change the value of a column of an inserted row, you won't do *another* (!) `INSERT`, i.e. produce another row, but set the value of the column of the `new` pseudo record.

However changing the values of the columns of an inserted row is only allowed in `BEFORE` triggers.

So what you actually want is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER correo
               BEFORE INSERT
               ON prueba
               FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET new.correo = concat(ucase(left(new.nombre, 1)), lcase(substring(new.apellido, 2)));
END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d44aae2264acb7257a594bc6f73389b0)

(Though your `concat()` doesn't produce an e-mail address as you described. But I guess that's just an irrelevant example?)

Comment: this works exactly how i wanted thank you